# ajax - pass variable to autocomplete for particular row

Tags: php, ajax

I have code like this

```
            $(function() {
              $('.serial_number').live('focus.autocomplete', function() { 
                $(this).autocomplete("/admin/includes/getinvoiceajax.php", {
                    width: 300,
                    matchContains: true,
                    mustMatch: true,
                    selectFirst: false
                }); 
              });
            });
```

which gets a list of serial numbers from a table. Right now it just gets the entire list, but I would like to pass a variable [man_part_number] into this so that I can refine my results. The problem is that I can't figure out how to pass man_part_number when it varies from input field to input field. It need to match for that particular row. I thought maybe I could serialize this.

```
<input type="hidden" name="man_part_number[]" id="man_part_number" class="man_part_number" />
<input type="text" name="serial_number[]" id="serial_number" class="serial_number" />
<input type="hidden" name="man_part_number[]" id="man_part_number" class="man_part_number" />
<input type="text" name="serial_number[]" id="serial_number" class="serial_number" />
<input type="hidden" name="man_part_number[]" id="man_part_number" class="man_part_number" />
<input type="text" name="serial_number[]" id="serial_number" class="serial_number" />
<input type="hidden" name="man_part_number[]" id="man_part_number" class="man_part_number" />
<input type="text" name="serial_number[]" id="serial_number" class="serial_number" />
```

Comment: try giving the input fields unique IDs or class names and grab it from within your function

Comment: but how do I even pass that variable for that row even if I changed the id. That's my question